# How to include speech marks (double quotes) in HTTP request body

Tags: c#, rest, post, httprequest

I am trying to create some code that uses TSheets REST API. The documentation states that this is the format I should use to create timesheets.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://rest.tsheets.com/api/v1/timesheets");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <TOKEN>");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "<REQUEST BODY>", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

and that this is what should go into the request body

```
{
 "data":
  [
    {
     "user_id":1242515,
     "type":"regular",
     "start":"2018-07-23T10:00:00-07:00",
     "end":"2018-07-23T13:10:23-07:00",
     "jobcode_id":"17288283",
     "notes":"This is a test of the emergency broadcast system",
     "customfields": {
      "19142":"Item 1",
      "19144":"Item 2"
     },
     "attached_files": [
      50692,
      44878       
     ],
    },
  ]
}
```

My question is how can I get the speech marks (double quotes) into the request body section? is there an escape character I need to put with the speech mark

Answer (score 2):

Use `\"` to represent `"`, A useful tool: https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html